# How do I tell GWT-Designer/windowBuilder where the UI is

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, windowbuilder, gwt-designer

While following this tutorial
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.html
GWT-Designer/windowBuilder stops being able to find the UI. I think this happens at step "Update the StockWatcher UI" when the UI widgets gets placed in a function.

Can I tell GWT-Designer/windowBuilder where to look for it or should I structure the app differently? (If so where could I find documentation on the correct structure?)

Comment: What do you mean by "stops being able to find the UI" ? Do you have an error message, a stack trace ?

Comment: If you click on the design tab the project seems empty because it isn't looking for the code in the right place.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help but I've found if the initialization method is removed, the windowbuilder doesn't know how to render the the user interface.  I think it gives an error message though saying it can't parse.  But it doesn't seem like you've gotten an error message.